# How do you set range: NSRangePointer in NSView knowsPageRange in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsrange

I'm trying to set the number of printed pages in an NSView using the `knowsPageRange` function. How do I correctly set the range: NSRangePointer?

```
override func knowsPageRange(_ range: NSRangePointer) -> Bool {
    let printOperation = NSPrintOperation.current!
    let printInfo: NSPrintInfo = printOperation.printInfo

    // Where can I draw?
    pageRect = printInfo.imageablePageBounds
    let newFrame = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: printInfo.paperSize)
    frame = newFrame

    // Construct the range to return
    var rangeOut = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)

    // Pages are 1-based. That is, the first page is 1.
    rangeOut.location = 1
    rangeOut.length = 10 // Number of pages

    // Return the newly constructed range, rangeOut, via the range pointer
    range.memory = rangeOut // Cannot assign to property: 'range' is a 'let' constant

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change:

```
range.memory = rangeOut
```

to:

```
range.pointee = rangeOut
```

The use of `pointee` is from Swift 3. `memory` is from Swift 2.